# Unable to get Maven Upstream packages to Azure DevOps Artifacts

Tags: git, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have a feed called (ABC) where I want to have all the upstream packages of Mavenand I was able to get maven upstream packages few days back in Azure DevOps Artifact but now, When I am trying to get the same upstream packages in other newly created feed with the same steps which I did earlier, I dont get Maven upstream packages, Can Somebody pls guide or suggest ?

Comment: Hi Kevin Lu-MSFT , Thanks for asking , I dont accept this as answer , I have chosen "Include packages from common public sources" this as Option but still not getting maven upsteam pacakges..Earlier got the feed but I eant this in another feed of 
 same project in ADO.

Comment: Hi @sunil Gupta. The package in Upstream Source will not be displayed directly in the azure feed. Only after you use this feed for package install, the feed will cache and display the packages used.